# Проблема с enum в java

Tags: java, sql, enum

В БД есть две таблички `t_statuses` и `t_operators`. В первой значения `(-1 - BANNED, 0 - OFFLINE, 1 - ONLINE)`, во второй собственно операторы, статус которых - внешний ключ (`status_id`) на первую таблицу. В java коде я вместо entity-класса для статусов сделал enum:

```
public enum OperatorStatus {
    BANNED(-1), OFFLINE(0), ONLINE(1);
    private int id;
    OperatorStatus(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public int getValue() { return id; }
}
```

В базе имеется одна запись со статусом `0 - OFFLINE`. Если в классе `Operator` поле статуса сделать типом Integer, то 0 в него и устанавливается. Но, если я создаю поле типа `OperatorStatus`, его значение становится равным `BANNED`, т.е. -1. С чем связано такое различие?

Comment: покажите как Вы создаете экземпляр OperatorStatus

Comment: Этим занимается Hibernate, для OperatorStatus указана только аннотация с указанием имени столбца

Answer (score 0):

когда создаешь поле типа `OperatorStatus`, думаю ты присваиваешь значение с `os.ordinal()` равным `0` - т.е. первое из списка
`int`/`Integer` тоже присваеваются нулю при инициализации
P.S. как ты объявляешь поле типа `OperatorStatus` и у тебя не возникает `NullPointerException`?